# Excel vba | running a access macro from excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I get the following message whenever  I try to execute the following code.

```
Sub Refresh_Pivot()
Dim AWB As Workbook
Dim pvtTable As Object
Dim appAccess As Object

'Save workbook
Set AWB = ActiveWorkbook
AWB.Save

   'Open Access Application
   Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
   appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "S:\AMA\MPF\MPF Projects\MPF Loss Emergence\MPFV4.accdb"
   appAccess.Visible = True

'Set Message bar in excel t o notify user of update process
oldStatusBar = Application.DisplayStatusBar
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Retrieving information, please be patient...."



  'Execute Access Macro containing lineup of queries and scrubs
  appAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro "0_Retrieve_Scrub"  '<-- As it appears in the Macro Group in the Access Interface.


       'Close Access

       appAccess.DoCmd.Quit


       'Return message bar to original status
        Application.StatusBar = False
        Application.DisplayStatusBar = oldStatusBar


    Set pvtTable = Worksheets("1. Roll Rate Pivots").Range("C13").PivotTable
    pvtTable.RefreshTable

    Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("C:j").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 13

  'Notify user process has completed
  MsgBox ("Update complete")
End Sub
```

It basically opens a Access dbase, runs a Access macro and closes Access. I have an ODBC connection to the table that is created by the macro in the same excel file that this code is triggered from. I have this running successfully in excel 2007. We recently upgrade office 2013, we started to receive this message. When we debug, it highlights this line of code. At first I though it had something to do with the object library for that version, all the latest one is checked. Has anyone encountered a similar issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**appAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro "0_Retrieve_Scrub"**

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQZCM.png)

Comment: Is Office 2013 a 64 bit version? Can you use check your linked table manager in Access to make sure it's still connected properly? Does the macro use RunCode to run a VBA function or is it step-thru Access commands?

Comment: We are running a 32 bit version of Office 2013. The really weird thing is when I copy the code to a brand new file (commenting out the pivot table refresh of course) it executes fine. "Docmd" is an Access vba method.

Comment: Perhaps security settings? Try setting the Macro settings to "Activate all macros", both in Excel and Access.

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% certain that the macro name you are referencing exists within the database being opened and that the leading 0 in the macro name isn't causing any issues?

Comment: yes, the macro name is not the issue because I am able to run the same code in another excel spreadsheet as stated in my other comment to dbmitch.

Comment: Ok. Well another approach you can try is instead of using that line to run a macro, have the opening of the database tied to a macro that automatically runs (even if the auto macro just calls this macro). Any macro called "AutoExec" will automatically run when the database opens. Create an autoexec macro which calls the macro you want to launch, and you shouldn't need the DoCmd line.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same error while attempting to run an Access Macro from Excel VBA.

Change this:

```
appAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro "0_Retrieve_Scrub"  '<-- Error line referring to Access subroutine`
```

To this:

```
appAccess.Run "0_Retrieve_Scrub"
```